# Excessive Temp and Frequency Limiting Under Load

Tags: cpu, temperature, cpu-temperature, cpu-throttling

I've got a [DG41WV Intel board](https://ark.intel.com/products/48621/Intel-Desktop-Board-DG41WV) running a [Q6600 CPU](https://ark.intel.com/products/29765/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q6600-8M-Cache-2_40-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) with a stock cooler and a GeForce 8500 GT video card.

I had been having some trouble with seemingly random crashes and allot of noise from the cooler fan, especially when watching videos.  I cleaned the heat sink and put new thermal paste and ran [Prime95](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiqq6LsteHXAhUIthQKHWG8AFkQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mersenne.org%2Fdownload%2F&usg=AOvVaw2yw7qXFL4S-D0SwboIFXFj) to test stability.

What I found was that while the fan was way quieter, the cores where running between 91*-100* Celsius, and their frequency was being throttled from the CPU's rated 2.4Ghz down to 1.6Ghz.  I used [CPUID HWMonitor](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiRpc_-teHXAhVMXBQKHRK5AtIQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpuid.com%2Fsoftwares%2Fhwmonitor.html&usg=AOvVaw0Rm6Ozaes2YJeL-2PDMwXt) to view CPU frequency and the temps.

I ran Prime95 for about an hour, and while the computer didn't crash, the temperatures seem excessively high, and I would think the cpu's would be able to run at 100% load full speed even with the stock cooler.

Does this behavior indicate a failing CPU?

Comment: It is an indication of inadequate cooling.  Your cpu isn’t failing.  You should reapply the thermal paste you likely have to much

Comment: It's possible the fan or motherboard is failing.  Your CPU was debuted in '07 and your mobo in '10.  Desktops generally have a lifetime of 4-5 years.  Check your fan for speed and rattle, the heatsink for dust, and your mobo for blown or leaking capacitors.  Also, make sure the heatsink is seated correctly.  I've seen some plastic heatsink connectors break, causing uneven or nearly no contact with the CPU.

Comment: @computercarguy the fans is operating fine, I cleaned the heatsink, and it seems to be seated fine.  Why would blown or leaking capacitors cause the cpu to run hot, as opposed to just the system not even turning on?

Comment: Blown caps can cause a wide variety of issues.  I've seen mobos that had almost all their caps blown still power up and run.  I don't know how, but they did.  They tend to run like an 100 year old man, but they ran.  (Slow, lots of wheezing, and pauses.)  Depending on the cap, it could be powering the fan speeds or an unrelated function that is messing with things, somehow.

Comment: BTW, did you replace the thermal pad on the GPU with thermal paste?  I don't have experience with it, but I've heard that's a bad idea.  The pad is a design element that the paste doesn't replace, so it can leave gaps you aren't aware of.  From what you've said, I'm assuming you just replaced the CPU thermal paste, but am just checking.

Comment: @computercarguy Didn't touch the GPU.